# Wildcard in python dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying create a python dictionary to reference 'WHM1',2,3, 'HISPM1',2,3, etc. and other iterations to create a new column with a specific string for ex. White or Hispanic.  Using regex seems like the right path but I am missing something here and refuse to hard code the whole thing in the dictionary.

I have tried several iterations of regex and regexdict :

```
d = regexdict({'W*':'White', 'H*':'Hispanic'})
eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['Race'] = 
eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['EEOC_Code'].map(d)
```

A new column will be created with `'White'` or `'Hispanic'` for each row based on what is in an existing column called `'EEOC_Code'`.

Comment: `df` sounds like [tag:pandas] but this is really not possible to deduce from you short code snippet. Please [edit] your question to identify any third-party libraries you use. Maybe see also the guidance for writing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions are wrong - you appear to be using glob syntax instead of proper regular expressions.

In regex, `x*` means "zero or more of `x`" and so both your regexes will trivially match the empty string. You apparently mean

```
d = regexdict({'^W':'White', '^H':'Hispanic'})
```

instead, where the regex anchor `^` matches beginning of string.

There are several third-party packages [1](https://github.com/perimosocordiae/regexdict), [2](https://github.com/solos/regexdict), [3](https://github.com/LumenTheFairy/regexdict) named `regexdict` so you should probably point out which one you use. I can't tell whether the `^` is necessary here, or whether the regexes need to match the input completely (I have assumed a substring match is sufficient, as is usually the case in regex) because this sort of detail may well differ between implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have completely understood your problem. However, if all your labels have structure **W**HM... and **H**ISP..., then you can simply check the first character:

```
for race in eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['EEOC_Code']:
     if race.startswith('W'):
         eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['Race'] = "White"
     else:
         eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['Race'] = "Hispanic"
```

**Note**: it only works if what you have inside `eeoc_nac2_All_unpivot_df['EEOC_Code']` is iterable.